# linux suid program not preserve the euid after execv

Tags: linux, suid

Here is my c code snippet from `test.c`.

```
printf("ruid:%d, euid:%d\n",getuid(),geteuid());
char *args[] = {"/bin/bash","-c","exec id",0};
execv("/bin/bash",args);
```

I compile the code with `sudo gcc test.c -o test; sudo chmod +s ./test`, so program `test` has suid bit and is owned by root.

`printf` outputs as espected, `ruid:1000, euid:0`, but the program `id` indicates `ruid` and `euid` are both `1000`.

Comment: See [setuid bit seems to have no effect on bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74527/setuid-bit-seems-to-have-no-effect-on-bash)

Comment: Also see [Setuid Demystified](https://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2017/readings/setuid.pdf) by Chen, Dean and Wagner. Its an old paper but it still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Supply additional parameter "-p" to exec.

Here is an explanation copied from "man bash":

If the -p option is supplied at invocation, the startup behavior is the same, but the effective user id is not reset.